# Regular expression error while checking for a password

Tags: javascript, python, regex

In javascript I am trying to check that a password must be at least 8 characters long and must contains at least one letter, one digit and no special symbol other than _@.- .
for this I am using this regular expresson

```
^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z_@.-]{8,}
```

but when I am trying to match a string with it like

```
^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z_@.-]{8,}.test('password')
```

it is giving syntex error

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '^'
```

and I have to check the same thing in python also.

Comment: You forgot `/` to tell JS it **is** a regular expression

Comment: Why not use basic string methods? I'm sure JS has a reasonable set of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check these conditions in Python without regex:

```
def check_password(password):
    return len(password) > 7 and any(character.isalpha() for character in password) and any(character.isdigit() for character in password) and all(character.isalnum() or character in '_@.-' for character in password)
```

Alternatively:

```
def check_password(password):
    if len(password) < 8: return False
    alpha = digit = False
    nosymbol = True
    for character in password:
        if character.isalpha():
            alpha = True
        if character.isdigit():
            digit = True
        if not (character.isalnum() or character in '_@.-'):
            nosymbol = False
    return alpha and digit and nosymbol
```

Answer (score 4):

JS Regular expression literals need to be wrapped in `/`..`/`:

```
/^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z_@.-]{8,}/.test('password')
```

Comment: p.s. in Python, you'll use `re.search()` or `re.match()` : https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: same error after copying the answer also

Comment: Not here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/JdjygK

Comment: console.log(/^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%])[0-9a-zA-Z_@.-]{8,}/.test('password'))

Comment: You have two extra, invisible,  characters - Unicode #8204 and #8203 - right before `'password'` in your version. These are "zero-width space" and "zero-width non-joiner", which is why you can't see them. They're not legal here, apparently.

Comment: hmmmmm, then how can I see or remove these Unicode characters??

Comment: That's between you and your text editor.

Comment: I am using sublime text

Comment: Backspace works for me in ST.

Comment: People are upvoting the answer means it is helpful but still I am unable to remove the unicode characters you said :)